# Word spacing in font-face?

Tags: css, font-face

I can't find any documentation for this on the internet. I just put the Bebas font on my page like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasRegular';
    src: url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.svg#BebasRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

However, the font has too small gaps between words - sometimes it is hard to see where one word stops and the next word begins.

Is it possible to define the width between words in the font-face declaration?

Comment: Why don't you want to add `word-spacing` to the specific classes/tags, e.g. `<body>`? You need to specify the font-family anyway.

Comment: Hmm, that is a much better solution. I was thinking about "fixing the font" rather than "changing the font settings", if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [letter-spacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C8) property:

```
letter-spacing:2px;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) within the `@font-face` declaration to ignore the space character from the font. The browser will then render the space using a fallback font instead.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasRegular';
    src: url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/BEBAS___-webfont.svg#BebasRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    unicode-range: U+0000-001F, U+0021-007F;
}
```

The range specified in the last line is [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) (U+0000 through U+007F), skipping U+0020, which is the space character.

---

I believe that this approach is *better* than adjusting `word-spacing` because it will keep things looking clean even if the fallback font is used. Bebas's space character is just so narrow that you have to have a really large value for `word-spacing`, which looks pretty bad on most other fonts.